# Apache 404 error when accesing Magento Admin Panel

Tags: php, apache, magento

The problem is: I cannot access Magento admin panel In my fresh
Magento installation on my Debian 7 server.

Everything went fine during installation. All modules are installed and
I think permissions are ok (root folder and all files belong to www-data,
directory permission is set to 700 and file permission to 600, according to Magento documentation, but I tried something more permissive like 755 for folders and 644 for files without any success).

When accessing my store by url it loads but without css, javascript.
When accessing the admin panel I got 404 error from Apache.
Magento version: 2.0.0 CE

Here is a list of what I have tried so far:

1. Check if app/etc/local.xml has admin in it:

   - file does not exist
2. Set store_id, group_id, website_id and costumer_group_id to 0:

   - tables core_store, core_store_group, core_website and costumer_group don't exist
3. Use url like domain/magento/index.php/admin:

   - Apache is not able to find some index key
4. Delete app/etc/use_cache.ser

   - file does not exist

I'm really new to Magento, actually, this is my first attempt installing it. I'd appreciate any help, I have full access to server and database.
Thank you

**Update**

Now I can access my store by the url with css and images loading properly.
I did this:

```
    $ magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_BR
```

Which created the directory structure that was missing.

Then I reset the file ownership (www-data) and permissions (700 for folders and 600 for files).

Everything is fine, except that I cannot access the admin panel yet.

Comment: Point (1) your local.xml doesn't exist?? You can't have a functioning Magento installation without it

Comment: Yes, and I created it manually but nothing changed. I just uninstalled magento and started installing again.

Comment: Good idea. Magento should create the file and tables in point 1 and 2 during a successful installation. I imagine point 3 may be down to misconfigured Apache configuration, but might be fixed but a fresh reinstall too, and point 4 - I've never heard of that file so I'd ignore it for now if I were you.

Comment: its clearly permission issue. set your folder permission first then try again with installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on wamp server logo on start menu
Go to Apache->Apache modules->Enable rewrite_module

Restart wamp services again and check on your site

Comment: Thanks @dhaval-patel, but rewrite_module is enabled and I'm in a LAMP stack.